# inconsistency when using target object as input to quarto chunk options

Tags: r, target, quarto

I'm using [targets](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/) to develop a pipeline. At the end of the pipeline I want to generate a report (Quarto markdown) in which some chunks get evaluated depending on objects created during the pipeline.

I can recover the pipeline object using

```r
id <- tar_load(id)
```

and use the variable inside a chunk option:

```r
#| echo !expr id
# do some stuff if id == TRUE
```

But, the *eval* option works differently.

```r
#| eval: !expr id

# This should only get evaluated if id is TRUE
# but also raises an error when issuing tar_make()
# Error in eval(x, envir = envir) : object 'choice' not found
1 + 1 == 2
```

The chunk above gets evaluated correctly, that is, if result from expression is TRUE, it evaluates. But it also raises an error when issuing `tar_make()`

```
Error in eval(x, envir = envir) : object 'choice' not found
```

If I change the code chunk to `#| eval: !expr tar_read(choice)`, than no error is reported

Is this the expected behavior? Or is this an inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a problem with `Quarto`, not `targets`

https://github.com/ropensci/tarchetypes/discussions/137#discussioncomment-4767907